# Python imports or circular imports making my variables unaccessible

Tags: python, import, global-variables, undefined

I'm new to python and I have a program made of multiple modules, one of my variables is accessible in one of those modules but not in another one even if it should be. Error : 'line 52, in 
main(), line 37, in main displayingTree(), line 23, in displayingTree i.display(window)
NameError: name 'window' is not defined'.

This is my code :
File 1 :

```
# coding: utf-8

from variables import *
from bot_class import *
from tree_class import *
from movingBug import *
import pygame

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((gridWidth, gridHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption("Simulons la naissance d'une colonie")

def main():
    keepOn = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    areFirstBugs = False
    while keepOn:
        clock.tick(3)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                keepOn = False
        
        window.fill(backgroundColor)

        for x in range(0, gridWidth, cellSize):
            for y in range(0, gridHeight, cellSize):
                pygame.draw.rect(window, gridColor, (x, y, cellSize, cellSize), 1)
        
        if not areFirstBugs:
            firstBugsInit(areFirstBugs)
            areFirstBugs = True

        movingRedBugs()
        movingBlueBugs()
        displayingBug()
        displayingTree()


        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()

def firstBugsInit(areFirstBugs):
    Bug(len(redBugList) + 1, red, 300, 10, 10, 8)

    Bug(len(blueBugList) + 1, blue, 300, 590, 590, 8)

    Tree(len(treeList) + 1, green, 60, 290, 290, 10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

File 2 :

```
from variables import *
from bot_class import *
from bots_grid import *
import pygame

class Tree():

    def __init__(self, number, color, frequency, xPos, yPos, size):
        self.number=number
        self.color=color
        self.frequency = frequency
        self.xPos=xPos
        self.yPos=yPos
        self.size=size
        treeList.append(self)
    
    def display(self, window):
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, (self.xPos, self.yPos), self.size, self.size)


def displayingTree():
    for i in treeList:
        i.display(window)
```

File 3 :

```
from variables import *
from bots_grid import *
import threading
import pygame

class Bug():

    def __init__(self, number, color, maxAge, xPos, yPos, rayon): #maxAge est en seconde le temps qu'il reste au bug avant de mourir
        self.number=number
        self.color=color
        self.maxAge = maxAge
        self.xPos=xPos
        self.yPos=yPos
        self.rayon=rayon
        self.timer = threading.Timer(maxAge, self.destroy)
        allBugList.append(self)
        if color == red:
            redBugList.append(self)
        elif color == blue:
            blueBugList.append(self)
        self.planifyDeath()
    
    def display(self, window):
        pygame.draw.circle(window, self.color, (self.xPos, self.yPos), self.rayon)

    def planifyDeath(self):
        self.timer.start()

    def destroy(self):
        # Supprime le bug de la liste des bugs
        allBugList.remove(self)

        # Si le bug est bleu, le supprime également de la liste des bugs bleus
        if self.color == blue:
            blueBugList.remove(self)
            print('Bug '+ str(self.number) +' bleu est mort')

        # Si le bug est rouge, le supprime également de la liste des bugs rouges
        if self.color == red:
            redBugList.remove(self)
            print('Bug '+ str(self.number) +' rouge est mort')

        # Supprime le timer
        self.timer.cancel()

def displayingBug():
    for i in allBugList:
        i.display(window)
```

displayingBug() works well but displayingTree doesnt (in my vision it should but it doesnt).
Does anyone know this problem and could explain it to me ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please reduce this to a [mre] without third-party dependencies (i.e., pygame)? Also, we need to know the names of your files, not just "file 1", etc.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).